# Port mendeley citations from word to latex by copy paste

Tags: bibtex, msword, latex-to-word

I am looking for a way to make Mendely citations return the citation key (idealy even with a /cite{} wrapped around it as well). Instead of a number like [1] i would like to have  \cite{AutorYear} as a handle in my Word dokument so I can just copy paste the text to latex.

This question has been asked in a similar fashion alredy 5 years ago ([transferring inline citations from MS word to LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121170/transferring-inline-citations-from-ms-word-to-latex)) - but no one came up with that solution the person asked for. Therfore I wanted to ask if someone had found a solution to that issue in the meantime.

One of the suggested solutions in that thread involved a style written in .xsl which I can not translate to .csl  used by Mendely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transferring inline citations from MS word to LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121170/transferring-inline-citations-from-ms-word-to-latex)

Comment: I did clealy state that alredy... but the question is still unanswered and the theread has not be active for at least a year.

Comment: If I understand correctly this question is really about Mendeley and its interaction with MS Word. (La)TeX is only relevant as the goal of the operation, it is not directly involved in the actions that need to be taken here. You may have a better chance of getting an answer if you ask at a dedicated Mendeley forum or an MS Word community.